# How do you convert strings (Logical Operations & Relational Operations) to symbolic objects? 

Tags: matlab

How do you convert strings (Logical Operations & Relational Operations) to symbolic objects? For example..

```
zz = '(xx>=-4 ) & (xx<-3 )'
```

How do you convert `zz` to a symbolic object?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `sym` command?

```
zz = sym('(xx>=-4 ) & (xx<-3 )');
```

This should work, if `xx` is already a symbolic expression, i.e. after

```
syms xx
```

Comment: Thank you.
Should this work in R2012a ?
This do not work in R2011b.